# How to hide view behind the view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview, android-xml

I'm placing a `textview` over a line as `textview` have light color background the line behind the `textview` is visible, I want to hide that portion of line thats behind `textview`, how can i do that

Thanks in advance!

Like this 
[image]

Comment: Can u draw the image roughly and attach the image

Comment: Could you answer?

Comment: I didn't got the exact question, If u can please share the rough image

Comment: might be easier to have 3 views. ImageView TextView ImageView

Comment: Could you answer so im able to understand better :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Nilesh" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="NILu" />


        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

> **OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: so you used layout to hide background line?

Comment: @blackHawk yes or you can also do with **`RelativeLayout`** check out first solution

Comment: @blackHawk i have done with two way first using RelativeLayout and second using Linear layout

Comment: the root layout is relative layout in my case im wrapping textview inside linear layout and placing over the line lets see the result....compiling

Comment: @blackHawk let me know if any query

Comment: @blackHawk Happy to help you

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in multiple ways using a RelativeLayout.

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_height="2dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10sp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Some Demo text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Other way can be as .

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_height="2dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10sp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Some Demo text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
         />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_height="2dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two options:

1. You use three views side-by-side to have line - text - line
2. You use two views in a `FrameLayout`: The first one will be the view for the line, and the second one the `TextView`, which will be drawn above the line. Make sure that the `TextView` has a non-transparent background and its `layout_width` is `wrap_content`. Depending on your desired result you might want to add some horizontal padding to the `TextView`, so that the line doesn't directly touch the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can either try it like following code

shape_line.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line"
    >
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF">
    </solid>
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#000000" />
    <size android:height="2dp" />
</shape>
```

Add this to your drawable folder.
and in your layout add following layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_bg_line"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Hello" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the output :[image]