# How to divide a layout by a real line in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to create an  interface similar to which is in the picture but I don't know how to add a line between `linearlayouts`

[image]

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47669105/how-to-hide-view-behind-the-view/47669272#47669272

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust it by your own

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                android:background="@color/Black"></View>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_clock"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                android:background="@color/Black"></View>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a line by creating a layout say a RelativeLayout and setting the height to 1dp and filling the background with with the color of the line you want:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is just one way you could create a line, there are other ways such as creating a custom resource background.

Another example with a break in the center (set the color of the center layout to match the background color of the screen):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/black">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/black">

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]